# How to put a border over a HTML5 video with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am building a website with a centered video, the problem is that inside the video are to black lines one on the right side on on the left, they aren't really big but they are bugging me and my colleagues.

Then I had the idea of laying a tiny border with the same color as my background inside the video element like this:

```css
#vid {
position: float;
margin-top: 100px;
height: 480px;
width: 854px;
border: 3px solid #ECECEC;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<video id="vid" loop autoplay autobuffer controls muted>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.mh-content.de/mh/video/MuH_Film_s_1.mp4">
  </source>
  <source type="video/webm" src="http://www.mh-content.de/mh/video/MuH_Film_s_1.webm"> 
  </source>
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.mh-content.de/mh/video/MuH_Film_s_1.ogg"></source>
</video>
```

I got the tip with the `box-sizing` from [this site](http://www.soyoucode.com/2012/quick-tip-draw-border-element-css).
I uploaded this but there was no border visible.
Tested it on a normal div box without a video and its working just fine.
I also tried putting the video in an extra div container and applying the `box-sizing: border-box` attribute to the container, still no border visible.

[Link to my website](http://prakti.mh-content.de/MuH/)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: could anybody explain the -1 to me is there a problem with my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The position element does not accept a value of float. please see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for a list of accepted css values.

I'm not entirely sure why you got a downvote, apart from the css error, I can only assume the person who did it, did not understand that the border in the video was a part of the video and no fault of your own.

The following solution puts the video within a box that is framed by another div that has a border on it.

```css
.vid-border{
  position: relative;
  height: 480px;
  width: 854px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#vid {
  position: absolute;
  top:-5px;
  left:-5px;
  height: 480px;
  width: 854px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-border">
    <video id="vid" loop autoplay autobuffer controls muted>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.mh-content.de/mh/video/MuH_Film_s_1.mp4">
        </source>
        <source type="video/webm" src="http://www.mh-content.de/mh/video/MuH_Film_s_1.webm">
        </source>
        <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.mh-content.de/mh/video/MuH_Film_s_1.ogg"></source>
    </video>
</div>
```

Play with the width and height of the vid-border box to overlay the video.

Comment: Did you find this solution helped to answer your question?